# QLineEdit в toolBar Pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, qlineedit, qtoolbar

Подскажите как вставить `QLineEdit`, в `QToolBar` и туда же кнопку, чтобы после нажатия на кнопку, выводился текст, который написан в `QLineEdit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом [QToolbar.addWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtoolbar.html#addWidget):

```
lineEdit = QLineEdit()
button = QPushButton()

action = toolBar.addWidget(lineEdit)
toolBar.addWidget(button)

button.clicked.connect(lambda : print(lineEdit.text()))
```

Answer (score 3):

> QAction *QToolBar:`addWidget(QWidget *widget)
>
> Добавляет данный виджет на панель инструментов как последний элемент панели инструментов.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
import configparser


class MyEngineView(QWebEngineView):
    ''' Класс браузера. '''
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None, ):
        super(MyEngineView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        # Существует сигнал загрузки для инициирования
        self.page().profile().downloadRequested.connect(self.on_downloadRequested)

    def createWindow(self,  type):
        ''' Внедрите щелчок, чтобы перейти по ссылке. '''
        
        return self  

    # Загрузите слот, к которому подключен сигнал
    def on_downloadRequested(self, download : "QWebEngineDownloadItem" ):
        # Загрузить объект QWebEngineDownloadItem;
        download.downloadProgress.connect(self._downloadProgress)
        download.finished.connect(self._finished)
        # Загрузить путь и имя файла загрузки
        old_path = download.path()
        suffix   = QFileInfo(old_path).suffix()
        # Загрузить тип файла
        filttype = download.mimeType()
        
        unkonw_suffix = filttype.split(r'/')[-1]
        path, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Save File", old_path,  "*."+unkonw_suffix + ";;" + "*."+suffix )
        if path != "":
            download.setPath(path)
            download.accept()

    def _downloadProgress(self , bytesReceived:"qint64", bytesTotal:"qint64"):
        self.bytesReceived = bytesReceived
        self.bytesTotal    = bytesTotal
        
    def _finished(self):
        print("Загрузка завершена")

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setWindowTitle('My Browser')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('icons/qtlogo.png'))     
        self.resize(750, 400)
        self.show()
        self.frame = 1
        
        # Установить браузер
        self.browser = MyEngineView()
        url="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1137385/qlineedit-%d0%b2-toolbar-pyqt5" 
        
        # Укажите URL-адрес, чтобы открыть интерфейс
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl(url))
        # Добавить браузер в окно
        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)

        # Создайте навигационную панель с QToolBar и создайте кнопку с QAction
        # Добавить панель навигации
        navigation_bar = QToolBar('Navigation')
        # Задайте размер значка
        navigation_bar.setIconSize(QSize(16, 16))
        #Добавить панель навигации в окно
        self.addToolBar(navigation_bar)

        # Класс QAction предоставляет абстрактные действия польз-го интерфейса, 
        # кот. могут быть размещены в виджетах.
        # Добавить кнопки для пересылки, возврата, остановки загрузки и обновления
        back_button = QAction(QIcon('icons/left.png'), 'Back', self)      
        next_button = QAction(QIcon('icons/right.png'), 'Forward', self)  
        stop_button = QAction(QIcon('icons/exit.png'), 'stop', self)
        reload_button = QAction(QIcon('icons/new.png'), 'reload', self)     
        
        back_button.triggered.connect(self.browser.back)
        next_button.triggered.connect(self.browser.forward)
        stop_button.triggered.connect(self.browser.stop)
        reload_button.triggered.connect(self.browser.reload)
  
        # Добавить кнопку в панель навигации
        navigation_bar.addAction(back_button)
        navigation_bar.addAction(next_button)
        navigation_bar.addAction(stop_button)
        navigation_bar.addAction(reload_button)
        
        # Добавить адресную строку URL
        self.urlbar = QLineEdit()
        self.urlbar.setText(url)
        # Пусть адресная строка реагирует на сигнал кнопки возврата каретки
        self.urlbar.returnPressed.connect(self.navigate_to_url)                  # !!!

        navigation_bar.addSeparator()
        navigation_bar.addWidget(self.urlbar)                                    # !!!    <<<=====<

        # Пусть браузер изменит соответствующий адрес URL-адреса
        self.browser.urlChanged.connect(self.renew_urlbar)

    def navigate_to_url(self):
        q = QUrl(self.urlbar.text())
        if q.scheme() == '':
            q.setScheme('http')
        self.browser.setUrl(q)

    def renew_urlbar(self, q):
        # Обновить ссылку на текущую веб-страницу в адресной строке
        self.urlbar.setText(q.toString())
        self.urlbar.setCursorPosition(0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PS. Пожалуйста всегда предоставляйте рабочий пример, который у вас в работе!!!